# How do i extract data of only end of month dates in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

**My data is this** [image: My data is this]

I want output like this:
[image: I want output like this]

Comment: How to get last date entries in excel https://www.exceltip.com/lookup-formulas/how-to-get-last-entry-by-month-in-excel.html

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a formula like this one?

```
=VLOOKUP(EDATE($E$1,ROW()),A:B,2,FALSE)
```

Here, column `A` has the dates and column `B` has data I want. `E1` holds the date of any `ultimo` (last day of a month). The formula is in row 2 so that `ROW()` returns 2. Therefore `EDATE($E$1,ROW())` will be the last day of the month 2 months after the date in `E1`. As the formula gets copied down `EDATE($E$1,ROW())` will produce different dates, all ultimos.

If you need to retrieve data from different columns use `COLUMN()±n` in place of the 2. That number will change incrementally as you copy the formula horizontally. ±n adjusts the first column so that you can refer to column `B` although the formula is in column `F`. If this were the case exactly you would use `COLUMN()-4`